# How can I print characters to screen like vim on linux?

Tags: c++, terminal, ansi-escape, tput

I'm writing a program that needs to modify the terminal screen buffer without using printf or stdout. On win32 I did that by using `CreateConsoleScreenBuffer()` and `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer()` then writing to the console screen buffer using `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()`. I want to do this on linux as well (kind of like how vim prints things out) but I can't find any way. It would also be great if there was a way to do this using the standard library!

Comment: The [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/) library.

Comment: Alternatively you can manipulate the screen by printing [escape sequences](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html).

Answer (score 0):

OP says

> without using **`printf`** or ***stdout***

you could use *stderr* (which usually points to the same terminal), e.g.,

```bash
    echo '\033[H\033[J' >&2
```

to clear the screen while writing to *stderr*.  Or you could use [`tput`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html), e.g.,

```bash
    tput clear >&2
```